# What are the merits of debug_and_release config feature in qmake?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I can see only one merit of the feauture: we are able to issue the `make all` commad.

Well, I do not call `make` in any point of my developer's life. I use Qt Creator and when I build the project I want it strictly as debug or as release. I guess this is an expeted behaviour by people.

But `debug_and_release` is on by default in Qt Creator. Is there a merit in this I can't see? Is there some sense in the unintuitive mess like this:

```
CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
    # debug
} else {
    # release
}
```

which people are learning by making mistakes and asking WTF questions all over the internet?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Downvote is nice, but can you leave a word at least? Why do you think I'm wrong?

Comment: But you're supposed to be psychic... ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [qMake: How exactly does qmake interpret the "CONFIG(debug, debug|release)" syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961866/qmake-how-exactly-does-qmake-interpret-the-configdebug-debugrelease-synta)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I switch it off:

```
CONFIG -= debug_and_release
CONFIG( debug, debug|release )  {
  CONFIG -= release
}
else {
  CONFIG -= debug
  CONFIG += release
}
```

UPD.

I've got it. My question is completely wrong. `debug_and_release` have not much to do with `debug` and `release`.

Comment: Well, no one is interested in the issue. OK, it works for me, I'll use it then.

Comment: Finally I worked out how to set the config from creator without having to change it in .pro as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `debug_and_release` option has almost nothing to do with qmake's "debug" and "release" build-modes, learn build-modes in the other answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75194443/8740349

### What's `debug_and_release` option?

`CONFIG += debug_and_release` just asks `qmake.exe` to generate the "`Makefile`" file in a way that supports building both build-modes.

#### In details:

`debug_and_release` causes qmake to parse script 3 times:

- Once without changing the build-mode which IDE sets.
- Once with ensuring `CONFIG` variable sets `release` as build-mode.
- Once with ensuring `CONFIG` variable sets `debug` as build-mode.

And that in above order (at least, if tested with qmake version 3.0).

Which normally results in qmake generating 3 files:

- `Makefile`
- `Makefile.release`
- `Makefile.debug`

> Where the "`Makefile`" file takes around 10 times less space,
> and does nothing but redirecting "make.exe" to "`Makefile.release`" file or "`Makefile.debug`" file.

However, if your script logs a single warning, qmake spams 2 additional warnings, which can be work-arounded by useing like:

```
!build_pass: warning("My message shown in IDE")
```

Or:

```
!build_pass {
    warning("My message shown in IDE")
}
```

Or:

```
if (!build_pass) {
    warning("My message shown in IDE")
}
```