# qMake: How exactly does qmake interpret the "CONFIG(debug, debug|release)" syntax

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I read though [HERE](https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#What_does_the_syntax_CONFIG.28debug.2Cdebug.7Crelease.29_mean_.3F_What_does_the_1st_argument_specify_and_similarly_what_is_the_2nd_.3F), yet I still don't understand the syntax of the `qmake CONFIG` variable. for example, if I have the following CONFIG settings in my `.pro file`:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    message("debug mode")
}else {
    message("release mode")
}
```

then, when running `qmake`, the following will be displayed in the Compile Output in Qt-Creator:

```
Project MESSAGE: debug mode
Project MESSAGE: debug mode
Project MESSAGE: release mode
```

knowing that I am building my project in a **"debug mode"**, then my questions are:

- **why not showing the "debug mode" message only** ? and why not showing it just once ?
- Then, since I am building in a "debug mode", **why the message "Project MESSAGE: release mode" is displayed** ?
- Exactly, **what the syntax: CONFIG(debug, debug|release) really means?** does it means that build in a debug mode, then again build in a debug mode and lastly build in a release mode ? I know that these brackets "{}" means a [scope](http://asoneofus.narod.ru/qt/qmake-commandreference.html) (old link was died, recommend [scope](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#scopes)) but how qmake interpret what is inside these brackets "()" ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In the article you linked to, it's said in the very beginning that the project file is processed three times. This should answer your first question; since it's processed three times, your message() is executed three times too. Why is it processed multiple times? Because qmake does not build your project! It only generates build instructions which are then used to actually build the project. In order to generate build instructions for all possible configurations, it needs to process the project file multiple times, one time for each configuration.

For your second question: your project is built only in debug mode if that's what you selected, but build instructions are created for release mode too, as already mentioned above. When using "make" with mingw for example (rather than Visual Studio), you get two Makefiles: `Makefile.Release` and `Makefile.Debug`. When it generates the release makefile, that's when "release mode" is printed.

Finally, `CONFIG(debug, debug|release)` evaluates to true if CONFIG contains "debug" but not "release", or if it contains both "debug" and "release" but "release" doesn't appear after the last occurrence of "debug". For example you might have this:

```
CONFIG += release debug release debug release debug
```

Since the last "debug" comes after the last "release", `CONFIG(debug, debug|release)` is true.

The first argument of CONFIG() ("debug" in this case) is the value that has to appear last. The second argument ("debug|release") is the set of values that the first argument is checked against.

Translating that to English would give something like this: evaluate to true if "debug" appears at least once and, in case "release" appears too, the last appearance of "debug" comes after the last appearance of "release".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is extremely important and helpful. However, I did not understand the part of the "statement evaluation". you mentioned that "`CONFIG(debug, debug|release)` evaluates to true if CONFIG contains debug etc...", what do you mean by "contains" ? do you mean defined as in `CONFIG += debug` ? if so, given that I have no such definition in my `.pro file`, then where this definition is located ? .. another thing, you  also defined this:`CONFIG += release debug release debug release debug`, what does it means to define "debug" and "release" like this ?

Comment: please, also excuse my too much questions as I can't find, at all, any internet source that explains it, not to mention your explanation is  very simple, concise and clear.

Comment: @hashDefine Qt Creator can add "release" to CONFIG when calling qmake. For example, if you select "Run qmake" in the "Build" menu and you've set your build to release mode, you can see it passes "CONFIG+=release" as argument to qmake. Since CONFIG can already contain "debug" in it (either because you've put that in your project file yourself, or it might come from an mkspec file), there has to be a way to override it. This is why the "appears last in CONFIG" rule exists. The example I gave was just that though; an example. There's no use in adding both "release" and "debug" to CONFIG yourself.

Comment: Personally I think debug|release corresponds to debug_and_release

Comment: @user1914692 A build is either debug or release. Cannot be both.

Comment: I mean, CONFIG(debug, debug|release) will be true, if we CONFIG debug, or CONFIG(debug_and_release). But anyway, it seems online official document is not very clear.

Comment: @Nikos C.: Could you make it clearer: when you explain `CONFIG(debug, debug|release)`,  the expression itself has two 'debug'.  When you explain the meaning, could you mark which `debug` in the expression is referred to for each 'debug' you mentioned in your explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @RobinHsu From http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#config-config: "As the order of values is important in CONFIG variables (i.e. the last one set will be considered the active config for mutually exclusive values) a second parameter can be used to specify a set of values to consider." So  "debug|release" is the set of possible symbols, while "debug" (the first argument) is the symbol that has to occur last for the statement to be true. Yes, qmake is a giant hack, and it's one of the reason why it was replaced by qbs :-)

Comment: @Nikos C.: Got it! Thank you very much. It confused me for so long. BTW, so it means: For the 2nd parameter, "debug|release" is the same as "release|debug".  Am I right?

Comment: @RobinHsu Yes, the order is irrelevant. Well, it *should* be irrelevant. Better try it to make sure.

Comment: I think a lot of the confusion arises from the fact that `qmake` uses two different namespaces for functions and variables, then uses the `CONFIG()` function to access the value of the `CONFIG` variable, rather than generalized functions e.g. `EQUALS(FILTER($$CONFIG, ["debug", "release"]), "debug")`

Comment: @NikosC. so why three times?

Comment: @YoavKlein It can be four times, even. There's not only debug and release configurations. There's others as well (like a configuration for profiling.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in qmake `debug` and `release` tell how Qt itself was built.
For example:

```
debug {
   # If Qt has binary built for debugging.
}

CONFIG(debug) {
    # Same as above.
}

release {
   # If Qt has binary built for release.
}

CONFIG(release) {
    # Same as above.
}
```

Knowing above, then how is a qmake-script supposed to know whether debug or release is being built?
Well, IDEs like "Qt Creator" do pass an option to `qmake.exe`, depending on build-mode, for example:

- "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"
- "CONFIG+=debug"
- "CONFIG+=release"

Finally:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    # If "debug" is added lastly to "CONFIG",
    # after all "debug or release" occurences,
    # which means, IDE asked for debug build.
}
CONFIG(debug, release|debug) {
    # Same as above.
}

CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    # If "release" is added lastly to "CONFIG",
    # after all "debug or release" occurences,
    # which means, IDE asked for release build.
}

CONFIG(release, release|debug) {
    # Same as above.
}
```

> Of course, `CONFIG(release, debug|release) {}` is not required, because `qmake` supports `else` keyword.

### What's `debug_and_release`?

So far so good, but there is also the `CONFIG+=debug_and_release` option, which for Windows may be even by default enabled.

The `debug_and_release` has almost nothing to do with qmake's "debug" and "release" build-modes,
and just asks `qmake.exe` to generate the "`Makefile`" file in a way that supports building both build-modes.

#### In details:

`debug_and_release` causes qmake to parse script 3 times:

- Once without changing what IDE is asking.
- Once with ensuring `release` is last in `CONFIG` variable.
- Once with ensuring `debug` is last in `CONFIG` variable.

And that in above order (at least, if tested with qmake version 3.0).

Which normally results in qmake generating 3 files:

- `Makefile`
- `Makefile.release`
- `Makefile.debug`

> Where the "`Makefile`" file takes around 10 times less space,
> and does nothing but redirecting "make.exe" to "`Makefile.release`" file or "`Makefile.debug`" file.

However, if your script logs a single warning, qmake spams 2 additional warnings, which can be work-arounded, like:

```
!build_pass: warning("My message shown in IDE")
```

Or:

```
!build_pass {
    warning("My message shown in IDE")
}
```

Or:

```
if (!build_pass) {
    warning("My message shown in IDE")
}
```