# Project Error: Could not find feature debug_and_release

Tags: sql, qt, qmake

I'm trying to install SQL Drivers on my Computer and im following this tutorial:
http://seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows

But when I got here:

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=%mysql%\\include" "LIBS+=%mysql%\\lib\\libmysql.lib"  -o Makefile mysql.pro
```

It gives me the above error

```
Info: creating stash file C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\sources\qtbase\.qmake.stash
Project Error: Could not find feature debug_and_release
```

This didn't happen when I followe this tutorial on my other computer.
How can I fix this?

Comment: The default is on but somehow off in the project file. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913770/what-are-the-merits-of-debug-and-release-config-feature-in-qmake

Comment: Hm, that's weird. How do I turn it back on? Where is the correct config file?

Comment: I can find dozens of qmake.conf files in my QT installation.

Comment: CONFIG += debug_and_release ?

Comment: Yeah, but where do I put it? When I put it in my qmake command with the other stuff I just get the same error.

Comment: The longer log should show where the error occur.